# Conditioned disjunction in Haskell

Tags: haskell

> Write a function that takes as input a list of Boolean values, the number of elements in which is a multiple of three, and returns a value that is obtained by sequentially applying the operation "conditional disjunction" to the k-th triple of list elements (the k-th triple is a triple of elements with numbers k, k+1 and k+2, k = 1,3,...,n-2). The result of applying the operation to the k-th pair of elements becomes the (k+2)th element of the intermediate list. Give three examples of using the function.

---

I have tried the following, but it doesn't work.

```hs
     calc::[Bool]->Bool
      calc [] = False
      calc (p:[]) = False
      calc (p:q:[]) = False
      calc (p:q:r:[]) = ((not q||p)&&(q||r)) 
      calc (p:q:r:xs) = calc(((not q||p)&&(q||r)):r:xs)
```

The compiller says the following.

```
21.hs:3:19: parse error on input ‘=’
```

Comment: If it is a multiple of three, then why do we move the cursor two steps each time?

Comment: Which compiler? Which version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your indentation is wrong - you've got separate function implementations for your patterns, so each of them should start on column 0:

```
calc::[Bool]->Bool
calc [] = False
calc (p:[]) = False
calc (p:q:[]) = False
calc (p:q:r:[]) = ((not q||p)&&(q||r)) 
calc (p:q:r:xs) = calc(((not q||p)&&(q||r)):r:xs)
```

See [Learn you a Haskell: Syntax in functions](http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions)

Comment: TY, It finally works